# Excel VBA - My dynamic array only contains the last value that's added

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to populate a dynamic array and it does work in terms of getting the right amount of values.
for example it needs to have 3 values it has 3 values but only the last one is like a real value.

To clear that up, This it what that array would look like:
`Array("", "", "actual string value")`
So the first 2 values are empty.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is the code:

```
    Dim LinkSheet As Worksheet
    Set LinkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resources")
    Dim LinkNameRange As Range
    Set LinkNameRange = LinkSheet.Range("Table4[Resource Name]")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim PlannedProjArr() As String
    i = 0

   'loop through all links and find the projects that the chosen employee is linked to

    For Each linkname In LinkNameRange
        If linkname = Employee Then
            ReDim PlannedProjArr(i)
            PlannedProjArr(i) = linkname.Offset(, -1).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next linkname

    'test if array works
    For x = 0 To UBound(PlannedProjArr)
        Debug.Print PlannedProjArr(x)
    Next x
```

It could even be that I'm testing it wrong or something. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use the preserve keyword with your redim statement to keep the values that were added previously

Comment: That could very well be the right answer. thank you i'll try that!

Comment: Of course that works, how stupid of me.. if you'd like you can put that in as an answer and i'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the preserve keyword with your redim statement to keep the values that were added previously

Preserve: Keyword used to preserve the data in an existing array when you change the size of the last dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Is your range a single column?

If so you can populate without looping and auto set the size of the array like this:

```
Sub testArray()
'Dim the array
Dim MyArr As Variant
'Set the Array to be the values of the range. We use transpose to change the orientation from columns going down to an array which goes accross
MyArr = Application.Transpose(Range("M1:M4"))
'Join the Array and display it for testing
MsgBox Join(MyArr, " - ")
End Sub
```

In  your case it would be something like:

```
PlannedProjArr = Application.Transpose(LinkNameRange)
```

If it is accross rows then you need to transpose TWICE like so:

```
Sub testArray()
'Dim the array
Dim MyArr As Variant
'Set the Array to be the values of the range. We use double transpose to change the orientation from rows to columns then back
MyArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("M1:O1")))
'Join the Array and display it for testing
MsgBox Join(MyArr, " - ")
End Sub
```